# How do I initialize an instance variable in a ruby Singleton?

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby class that is using the Singleton pattern.  I would like to initialize an instance variable as soon as the class is create (i.e instance is called). Where is the best place to do this?

```
require 'singleton'

class SingletonTest
  include Singleton
  @my_var # where / how should I initialize this
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do that in the constructor, i.e.

```
class MySingleton
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @something = 42
  end
end
```

You're guaranteed to have the constructor called before `.instance` returns.